# Solving a system of equations in R

Tags: r, equation-solving

I want to solve the following system of equations for b,c and d:

1 = b² + 6bd + 2c² + 15d²

1.75 = 2c(b² + 24bd + 105d² +2)

3.75 = d²(12 + 48bd + 141c² + d²)

Is there a general way to solve such systems of equations in R?